# Restriction estimates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question, harmonic-analysis

What is the defining property of what someone in the harmonic analysis community would call a "restriction estimate?"  I see sobolev norms, Fourier transforms, and inequalities relating these.  The one thing that I don't always see, but would expect given the name, is estimating the "size" of $f$ restricted to a hyperplane vs. $f$ on its entire domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me*, restriction estimate means a bound on the norm of an operator $T:X\to Y$ where

1. $X$ is some space of functions in a domain $\Omega$ (often the entire Euclidean space)
2. $Y$ is some space of functions on a subset $E\subset \Omega$ of *strictly smaller dimension* than $\Omega$ itself
3. For smooth functions, the operator agrees with the restriction $f\mapsto f_{|E}$.

The set $E$ is not always a hyperplane; it could be a manifold of some sort, or a more general set.   A quick look at randomly selected papers with this keyword did not produce counterexamples.

---

<sup>(*) a non-harmonic analyst</sup>